# NO DATA FOUND when selecting from temporary table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The following code block will *sometimes* error with "ORA-01403: NO DATA FOUND". In the first query, I retrieve data stored in a table on another database, and I store that data into a temporary table. In the second query, I select the data out of the temporary table INTO a local variable. I have to do this because one of the fields is a CLOB and [it is not possible to select a CLOB into a local variable across a database link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=database-links-and-lobs).

```
-- insert clob from remote database into temp table across database link
-- it will be deleted upon implicit commit when the report ends;
INSERT INTO  tmp_xml_result
SELECT add_id, site_cd, result_txt
FROM vw_add_result@ADifferentServer
WHERE add_id = p_add_id
    AND site = p_site;

-- now that clob is local, we can select it into a variable
SELECT xml
INTO v_xml
FROM tmp_xml_result
WHERE id = p_add_id
    AND site = p_site;
```

This block does not always error. When it does error, the second query throws NO DATA FOUND.

**How can I adjust this code block so that it never results in a "ORA-01403: NO DATA FOUND" error?** I know I can wrap the block in a `BEGIN / EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND... / END` block, but **the ideal solution will return the contents of the temporary table once they *are* available**.

My environments use "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production".

Comment: *"but the ideal solution will return the contents of the temporary table once they are available."* - Could you please elaborate on this? I think using an EXCEPTION block to handle no_data_found would be a better idea.

Comment: Why does your code occasionally hurl NO_DATA_FOUND? Could it be that sometimes you're querying your remote view with criteria that don't return any rows? If so, wouldn't you want to know that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check sql%Rowcount after the insert - if it is > 0, then proceed, otherwise do something else.

Or run a count(*) query after the insert - if it is 0, don't run your select . . into.

Or add an exception block to catch the ORA-01403.

Comment: I think checking `sql%Rowcount` is the best suggestion.